# Python Узнать все о процессоре

Tags: python, процессор

Я хочу написать программу которая будет `отпровлять данные о компьютере в базу данных` и я бы хотел узнать как я могу получить характеристики процессора в `python`

Мне надо:

- Получение полного имени процессора, по типу "Intel Core i7"
- Получать Ghz процессора

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo в линукс

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы можете установить пакет `cpuinfo`:

```
pip3 install py-cpuinfo
```

Что бы получить имя процессора:

```
import cpuinfo
cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand_raw']
```

Вывод:

```
'Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8145U CPU @ 2.10GHz'
```

Comment: обновить железо не хочешь?)

Comment: @Lofectr Да ноут взял на последние год назад, стационарного благо хватает дома. А ноут главное что бы Sublime тянул)

Comment: 8 поколение не такое уж старое)) где-то пыхтят ещё 6-ые